# How do I link to paths based on current_user roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an app using devise, cancan and rolify that redirects on login to a page specific to their roles. What I am trying to figure out is how I can link to that same path elsewhere in the app, not just as a redirect?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case current_user.roles.first.name
      when 'admin'
        users_path
      when 'yin'
        content_yin_path
      when 'yang'
        content_yang_path
      when 'yin_yang_lite'
        content_yin_yang_lite_path
      when 'yin_yang_pro'
        content_yin_yang_pro_path
      else
        root_path
    end
  end

end
```

Basically, I am looking for how to get to the current_user => role => path, or current_user_role_path

Comment: Do you just want the same method as shown above usable for `link_to` in the views/controllers? If so, you can define it as a helper method by adding this macro to your ApplicationController: `helper_method :after_sign_in_path_for`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I knew it was something simple that I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: I made the suggestion into an answer so you can accept it and get it out of the unanswered list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define any controller method to also act as a helper method using the `helper_method` macro in the controller. For your case:

```
ApplicationController

helper_method :after_sign_in_path_for
```